# How do I verify origin url on einaros' ws websocket package

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I've tired the code below it isn't worked:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wsServer = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080});

wsServer.on('connection', function(ws) {   
    if (ws.origin != 'http://example.com') {
        console.log('Origin was not http://example.com');
        return;
    }
});
```

This code is working fine with worlize's websocket server package. But I prefer einaros' better.
However, when I investigate ws.property, it contains something like below:

```
headers: {
    ...
    origin: 'http://example.com'
    ...
},
```

So how do I verify the origin of browser request.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find it eventually:

```
var domain = ws.upgradeReq.headers.origin;
```

Comment: This only seems to work if the browser does in fact set that header value. In other words: It is not reliable as it depends on cooperation of the client.

Comment: The `Origin` header is part of the WebSocket protocol, so all clients will support it. ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers): "All browsers will send an Origin header.")

Answer (score 2):

Searching from source code I found out a solution that is acceptable for me.
Through verifyClient option

```
var webSockOpts=
    {port         :myport
    ,verifyClient : function (info, callback) {
        var question=url.parse(info.req.url, true, true);
        if (parseInt (question.query.API_KEY) === 123456789) {
           status= true; // I'm happy
           code  = 400;  // everything OK
           msg   = '';   // nothing to add
        } else {
           status= false; // I'm noy happy
           code  = 404;  //  key is invalid
           msg   = 'Demo requires API_KEY=123456789';
        }
        callback (status,code,msg);
      }
}
wsServer=new webSocket (webSockOpts);
```

In your HTML/JavaScript add something like:

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + host + ':4081' + '/log?API_KEY=123456789');
```